Nothing prints when i type input into the serial monitor
I am new to Arduino. I am trying to learn how to use receive data over USB, but it is not working.
This is my code:
struct arrayData{
    char* array;
    int size;
}; 

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    //Create struct
    struct arrayData* myStruct = (arrayData*) errorHandling(malloc(sizeof(arrayData)));
    if(myStruct == NULL) return;
    myStruct -> size = 0;
    myStruct -> array = (char*) errorHandling(malloc(sizeof(char)));
    if(myStruct -> array == NULL) return;
    myStruct -> array[0] = '\0';
    // Read serial input buffer
    myStruct = readBuffer(myStruct);
    if(myStruct == NULL) return;
 
    // Print each byte
    for(int i = 0;i < myStruct -> size;i++){
        Serial.print(myStruct -> array[i]);
    }
    
    // Free
    free(myStruct -> array);
    myStruct -> array = NULL;
    free(myStruct);
    myStruct = NULL;
    
}

arrayData* readBuffer(arrayData* arrayMeta){
    // NOT RECOMMENDED!! abstracted malloc may cause mem leak
    // If array is NULL create it
    if(arrayMeta -> array == NULL){
        arrayMeta -> array = (char*) errorHandling(malloc(sizeof(char)));
        if(arrayMeta -> array == NULL) return NULL;
        arrayMeta -> size = 1;
    }
    // If Serial input buffer is not empty read
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
        char byte = Serial.read();
        int x = 0;
        // While buffer is not empty and we have not recieved end of transmission
        while(byte != '\n' && Serial.available() > 0){
        
            // Make array the right size
            arrayMeta -> array = (char*) errorHandling(realloc(arrayMeta -> array, (x+1) * sizeof(char)));
            if(arrayMeta -> array == NULL) return NULL;
            // Update the size member of struct
            arrayMeta -> size = x+1;
            // Write into array
            arrayMeta -> array[x] = byte;
            // Read next byte
            byte = Serial.read();
            x++;
        }
    }
    return arrayMeta;
}

// Return ptr on success and NULL on failure
void* errorHandling(void* ptr){
    if(ptr == NULL){
        Serial.println("Malloc failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    return ptr;
}

I have a feeling it has to do with freeing the memory or something like that because when messing around I inputted, "ggggg" and it outputed:
ggggg
gggg
ggg
gg
g
But the code is slightly different now and I can't reproduce that.
Also, when I put Serial.println(); after the for loop, some random characters print then its just a ton of newlines.
EDIT:
I made some changes and the following works, but random characters sometimes don't print and I can't figure out why.
For example typing "qwerty" sometimes prints qwety or qwery or qwert or qert.
#define PERFORMANCE 10

struct arrayData{
    char* array;
    int size;
}; 
 struct arrayData* myStruct;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Create struct
    myStruct = (arrayData*) errorHandling(malloc(sizeof(arrayData)),'0');
    if(myStruct == NULL) return;
    myStruct->size = 0;
    myStruct->array= NULL;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    
    // Read serial input buffer
    myStruct = readBuffer(myStruct);
    if(myStruct == NULL) return;
 
    // Print each byte
    if(myStruct->array != NULL){
        for(int i = 0;i < myStruct->size;i++){
            Serial.print(myStruct->array[i]);
        }
    }
    
    // Free
    free(myStruct->array);
    myStruct->array = NULL;
}

arrayData* readBuffer(arrayData* arrayMeta){
    // NOT RECOMMENDED!! abstracted malloc may cause mem leak
    // If array is NULL create it
    if(arrayMeta->array == NULL && Serial.available() > 0){
        arrayMeta->array = (char*) errorHandling(malloc(sizeof(char)),'2');
        if(arrayMeta->array == NULL) return NULL;
        arrayMeta->size = 1;
    }
    // If Serial input buffer is not empty read
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
        char byte;
        int x = 0;
        // While buffer is not empty and we have not recieved end of transmission
        while(Serial.available() > 0){
            // Read next byte
            byte = Serial.read();
            if (byte == '\n') break;
            // Make array the right size
            if(arrayMeta->size == x){
                arrayMeta->array = (char*) errorHandling(realloc(arrayMeta->array, (x  + PERFORMANCE) * sizeof(char)),'3');
                if(arrayMeta->array == NULL) return NULL;
                // Update the size member of struct
                arrayMeta->size++;
            }
            // Write into array
            arrayMeta->array[x] = byte;

            x++;
        }
        if(arrayMeta->size != x){
                arrayMeta->array = (char*) errorHandling(realloc(arrayMeta->array, (x) * sizeof(char)),'4');
                if(arrayMeta->array == NULL) return NULL;
                // Update the size member of struct
                arrayMeta->size = x;
            }
    }
    return arrayMeta;
}

// Return ptr on success and NULL on failure
void* errorHandling(void* ptr, char error){
    if(ptr == NULL){
        Serial.println("Malloc failed, error:");
        Serial.println(error);
        return NULL;
    }
    return ptr;
}


Style guide: the dot . and arrow -> operators bind very tightly
because they are postfix operators.
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing arrayMeta -> array is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use arrayMeta->array.

You say nothing is printed, presumably from the loop() function.  Have you checked whether the function returns early — there are three return statements before the printing.  Two of those return statements leak the memory allocated previously.

@JonathanLeffler Thank you. How would I check?

Also the reason why I think that it has to do with free, is because adding in the ...= NULL changes the garbage output that I get from adding Serial.println();

You'd wrap the return; in braces and add a print operation before it to report which one is exiting.  You're using Serial.println in errorHandling() to report problems and Serial.print to print information, but you're not checking whether those succeed.  I don't know whether those functions report a status — if they don't, you've got problems.  But ideally, you'd report the errors to a different location (usually using stderr — I'm not sure how that translates in your environment).

https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

@Juraj sent a useful link that told me what i needed to do to get it to work.
I needed to add delay(10) in the while loop, because i need to wait for the bytes to come in before checking if there were any left. What was happening was that the readBuffer() function would get called and only read 1 character and then Serial.available() would return 0, because i hadn't given enough time for the next byte to be sent over.
